# JPA 3 Hibernate + PostgreSQL 9.6.3 errors in queries with limitation

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

After upgrade to  Spring Boot 3 I`ve got next problem;
My entity

```
@Data
@Table(name = "campaign_status")
@Entity
public class CampaignStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "campaign_status_id")
    private Long campaignStatusId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

My jpa repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface CampaignStatusDao extends JpaRepository<CampaignStatus, Long> {
    CampaignStatus findTop1ByName(String status);
}
```

And I get the next errorin console

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        c1_0.campaign_status_id,
        c1_0.name 
    from
        campaign_status c1_0 
    where
        c1_0.name=? fetch first ? rows only

2023-01-26T11:43:12.854+02:00  WARN 18183 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-01-26T11:43:12.854+02:00 ERROR 18183 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
  Position: 99
```

I tried with PostgreSQL 9.6.24 and there is no ERROR with the same code. But upgrade db version in production will be very painful. So may be there is a way to figure it out.
By the way the same error if I try to execute jpa method with paging

Comment: You shouldn't be be using 9.6 any more anyways. And most definitely not 9.6.3 in production. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Comment: Implement a custom dialect that extends `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` and overrides the [getLimitHandler](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.java#L728) to return the `org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitOffsetLimitHandler.INSTANCE`. Then configure Hibernate to use that.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a PostgreSQL bug. Try updating to the latest 9.6 version, or even better, update at least to version 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution suggested in the comments helped.

Implement a custom dialect that extends `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` and overrides the `getLimitHandler` to return the `org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.LimitOffsetLimitHandler.INSTANCE`.

Then configure Hibernate to use that.
specify in properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=your.package.CustomPostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue in FindTop, FindFirst, FindFirst10 after Spring Boot 3 migration when my development db ran at PostgreSQL 9.6.5.
I suspected that it was a version issue b/w JPA & PostgreSQL.
I then checked with my QA & Others env they are running at PostgreSQL 11.6.
So at the time, there is no issue.

**Solution 1:**
Upgrade your db to higher versions. That will do.

**Solution 2**
Go with Native Query