# Postgresql giving syntax error for offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My spring batch application works fine with postgre version 'PostgreSQL 9.5.19'. I have to run this in a different environment with postgre version 'EnterpriseDB 9.5.0.5'. The following error comes. Is this a version problem? How to resolve this?
Even though error says it is syntax problem, following select is working when it is executed in dbtool.

```
2023-07-13T03:06:51.166+05:30  WARN 32448 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-07-13T03:06:51.167+05:30 ERROR 32448 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"
  Position: 549
2023-07-13T03:06:51.337+05:30 ERROR 32448 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step swedbank.eod.file_gen.etl.to.file.step in job swedbank.eod.file_gen.job

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select t1_0.trxn_no,t1_0.added_date,t1_0.auth_code,t1_0.base24_header,t1_0.crd_acpt_name_loc,t1_0.crd_no,t1_0.cashback_amt,t1_0.de63_1,t1_0.de63_19,t1_0.de63_ret,t1_0.de55,t1_0.exp_date,t1_0.frwd_inst_id,t1_0.merc_cat_code,t1_0.crd_acpt_id_code,t1_0.offline_flag,t1_0.particulars,t1_0.pos_cond_code,t1_0.pos_ent_mode,t1_0.proc_code,t1_0.retr_ref_no,t1_0.service_code,t1_0.term_id,t1_0.trxn_amt,t1_0.trxn_crtd_time,t1_0.trxn_curr_code,t1_0.trxn_typ from swt_dx_trxn_eod t1_0 where t1_0.added_date=? order by t1_0.trxn_no offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only] [ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"
  Position: 549] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy115.findByaddedDate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:283) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader.doInvoke(RepositoryItemReader.java:265) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader.doPageRead(RepositoryItemReader.java:228) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader.doRead(RepositoryItemReader.java:174) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:95) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.RepositoryItemReader$$SpringCGLIB$$0.read(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:189) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:362) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:139) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:129) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:389) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:313) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:256) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:362) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:139) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:241) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:227) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:167) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:142) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:316) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.westpay.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>eod</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eod</name>
    <description>Batch processing for eod file</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

property file

```
# Datasource
app.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
app.datasource.ip=10.5.50.10
app.datasource.port=54765
app.datasource.name=db
app.datasource.username=user
app.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${app.datasource.ip}:${app.datasource.port}/${app.datasource.name}

# JPA
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

Step class related to this issue

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class EnrichFileEodTableStepConfiguration extends AbstractStepProvider {

    @Autowired
    TransactionFileEodRepository transactionFileEodRepository;

    @Bean
    protected Step EnrichFileEodTable(TaskExecutor taskExecutor, JobRepository jobRepository,
                                  PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                  ItemReader<TransactionEod> transactionExtractRepositoryReader,
                                  ItemProcessor<TransactionEod, TransactionFileEod> transactionTransformItemProcessor,
                                  ItemWriter<TransactionFileEod> transactionLoadItemWriter){

        return new StepBuilder(SwedBankEodFileGenerationJobProvider.NAMES_PREFIX + "etl.to.file.step", jobRepository)
                .<TransactionEod, TransactionFileEod> chunk(GLOBAL_CHUNK_SIZE, transactionManager)
                .reader(transactionExtractRepositoryReader)
                .processor(transactionTransformItemProcessor)
                .writer(transactionLoadItemWriter)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                //.taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemReader<TransactionEod> transactionExtractRepositoryReader
            (TransactionEodRepository transactionEodRepository,
             @Value("#{jobParameters[" + PARAM_CUTOFF_DATE_TIME + "]}") LocalDateTime cutoffDate){
        try {
            return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<TransactionEod>().name("ExtractTransactionReader")
                    .methodName("findByaddedDate")
                    .arguments(Arrays.asList(cutoffDate.toLocalDate()))
                    .sorts(Collections.singletonMap("trxnNo", Sort.Direction.ASC))
                    .repository(transactionEodRepository)
                    .pageSize(GLOBAL_CHUNK_SIZE)
                    .build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<TransactionEod, TransactionFileEod> transactionTransformItemProcessor(){
        return new EnrichFileEodItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RepositoryItemWriter<TransactionFileEod> transactionLoadItemWriter(){
        try{
            return new RepositoryItemWriterBuilder<TransactionFileEod>().methodName("save").repository(transactionFileEodRepository).build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Batch configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {
    public static final int GLOBAL_CHUNK_SIZE = 100;
    public static final String NETWORK_ID = "36";
    @Value("${app.datasource.username}")
    private String databaseUserName;
    @Value("${app.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${app.datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;
    @Autowired
    DBPWDStoreClient client;

    /**
     *
     * @return JobLauncher that is used to launch the batch job. this is overriden because to have an async job launcher
     */
    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        try {
            jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException("Unable to configure the default job launcher", e);
        }
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    /**
     * @return async TaskExecutor
     */
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        //asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(2);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return PlatformTransactionManager
     */
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        String sPassword = client.getPassword(databaseUserName);
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSourceBuilder.url(dataSourceUrl);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(databaseUserName);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(sPassword);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionEodRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionEod, Long> {
    Page<TransactionEod> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE TransactionEod t WHERE t.addedDate = :added_date")
    int deleteEodTransactionsByAddedDate(@Param("added_date") LocalDate added_date);
    @Query("from TransactionEod t WHERE t.addedDate = :addedDate")
    Page<TransactionEod> findByaddedDate(@Param("addedDate") LocalDate addedDate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: @M. Deinum, do you have any idea about this question

Comment: You are using an old, unsupported version of PostgreSQL that doesn't understand the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` syntax.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the `spring-context` dependency and `hibernate-core` dependency. Next upgrade to Spring Boot 3.1.1 to get a bit more recent versions. Try without specifing the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` property. This will force HIbernate to select the best version of the dialect and probably adapt to your version of PostgreSQL. If not it will run with some newer version always instead of adapting.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe but if I execute that query directly in DB, it works. Issue comes when execute through hibernate.

Comment: @M. Denium I changed things accordingly. issue still exist.
HHH000511: The 9.5.0 version for [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect] is no longer supported, hence certain features may not work properly. The minimum supported version is 10.0.0. Check the community dialects project for available legacy versions.
2023-07-13T12:19:04.428+05:30  INFO 24520 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.dialect                : HHH035001: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, version: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$DialectResolutionInfoImpl@697d6ded

Comment: You are right; I didn't check. 9.5 already understood this syntax. You'll have to look at the PostgreSQL log and get the actual SQL statement executed. Add that to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it's in the question
select t1_0.trxn_no,t1_0.added_date,t1_0.auth_code,t1_0.base24_header,t1_0.crd_acpt_name_loc,t1_0.crd_no,t1_0.cashback_amt,t1_0.de63_1,t1_0.de63_19,t1_0.de63_ret,t1_0.de55,t1_0.exp_date,t1_0.frwd_inst_id,t1_0.merc_cat_code,t1_0.crd_acpt_id_code,t1_0.offline_flag,t1_0.particulars,t1_0.pos_cond_code,t1_0.pos_ent_mode,t1_0.proc_code,t1_0.retr_ref_no,t1_0.service_code,t1_0.term_id,t1_0.trxn_amt,t1_0.trxn_crtd_time,t1_0.trxn_curr_code,t1_0.trxn_typ from swt_dx_trxn_eod t1_0 where t1_0.added_date=? order by t1_0.trxn_no offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only

Comment: You don't really need the `@Query` can you remove that and try again? I wonder what the query would become then (although it probably will very similar if not equal (just trying to rule things out).

Comment: No, that is not the query. It contains `?`, which is not SQL. Please do what I say and dig in the PostgreSQL logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to jdbc driver / DB server mismatch.
For PostgreSQL, Hibernate used an internal class (now [LimitOffsetLimitHandler](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/pagination/LimitOffsetLimitHandler.html)) for paging, then it switched to [OffsetFetchLimitHandler](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/pagination/OffsetFetchLimitHandler.html). We could switch back by defining our own PostgreSQLDialect:

```
public class MyPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

    @Override
    public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
        return LimitOffsetLimitHandler.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

By using an older grammer, we may support a wider range of DB versions.

Comment: yes this solved my issue. this answer is also in following question. thank you @Will Phi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75244561/jpa-3-hibernate-postgresql-9-6-3-errors-in-queries-with-limitation

Answer (score 1):

The [`PostgreSQLDialect`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.java) in Hibernate 6.2 and up is, as the sources say for PostgreSQL 10 and up. As you are using 9 YMMV with the compatibility of that dialect.

The version in [Hibernate 6.1](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.java) is supporting PostgreSQL 8 and up.

That being said I would suggest you do the following

1. Remove `hibernate-core` as a dependency (included through `spring-data-starter-jpa`).
2. Remove `spring-context` as a dependency (included otherwise already)
3. Remove `validation-api` (the version you added isn't supported and if you want validation add `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead)
4. add `hibernate.version` with `6.1.7.Final` as a value to the `<properties>` section of your `pom.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.westpay.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>eod</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eod</name>
    <description>Batch processing for eod file</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.1.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I made all changes in pom. but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Then please add your code/configuration to your question. As it must be something in your configuration that is causing this.

Comment: added the step class related to this issue, related repository and Batch config class